# Apple Pay Payment Services Exception merchantId=1234ABCD not registered for domain=xyz.com

Tags: applepay, applepayjs

I experienced this error when my server made a session token request to start an "Apple Pay on the Web" session.

Answer (score 2):

Causes of this error include:

1. Registering the www or root merchant domain with Apple Pay but not redirecting one to the other, will cause this error.
2. Merchant domain that hasn't been verified, or was verified once but Apple cannot reach the file /.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt on your domain.

Solution:
Go to the Apple Developer account, to `Identifiers`. Select `Merchant IDs` from the right drop-down. Select the merchant identifier.

Scrolling down to `Merchant Domains` I saw that my domain `status` was `pending`.

Select `Verify` then `Download`. Download the verification file and place it in the .well-known folder per Apple's instructions.

3. You need valid payment processing certificate as well as a valid merchant identity certificate.